# What is the limit of $(1-x)^\frac{1}{x}$ as x approaches 0?

Tags: limits

Basically, if something has a probability of 1/5, doing it 5 times gives a probability of it *not* happening that's close to that formula. Doing something with a probability of 1/100 100 times makes it even closer. I'm wondering if this is a well-known named constant, the way these probabilities converge is interesting to me.

Comment: If $x=1/n$ then this becomes $$\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n$$ which has a ver well-known limit as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Seee (sorry), See e https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)#History

Comment: This is about the second most famous mathematical constant.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+expansion+of+(1-x)%5E(1%2Fx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n=\frac1x$.  You get $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-\frac1n)^n=\frac1e$.

Comment: I didn't identify that it was just the reciprocal of e, thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Determine first the limit of the logarithm: $\;\dfrac1x\,\ln (1-x)=\dfrac{\ln(1-x)-\ln 1}x\;$ is a rate of variation.

Answer (score 0):

By the Binomial theorem,

$$\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\left(-\frac1n\right)^k
\\=1-\frac nn+\frac{n(n-1)}{2n^2}-\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!n^3}+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{4!n^4}-\cdots\left(-\frac1n\right)^n
\\=\frac12\left(1-\frac1n\right)-\frac1{3!}\left(1-\frac1n\right)\left(1-\frac2n\right)+\frac1{4!}\left(1-\frac1n\right)\left(1-\frac2n\right)\left(1-\frac3n\right)-\cdots\left(-\frac1n\right)^n$$

The constant term of this expression is, for unbounded $n$,

$$\frac12-\frac1{3!}+\frac1{4!}-\cdots\to e^{-1}$$

Then coefficient of $\dfrac1n$ is

$$-\frac12+\frac{1+2}{3!}-\frac{1+2+3}{4!}-\cdots \frac{(n-1)n}{2n!}\cdots\to -\frac{e^{-1}}2$$

So the first order approximation is

$$\left(1-x\right)^x=\frac1e-\frac x{2e}.$$

Comment: Undue downvote.